# WebRtc on slow connection

Tags: webrtc

i have already used webrtc and socketIo on my project. Normally they are working well, however when the connection is slow down, seems two browsers can connect, but the webcam or voice does not show! I don't know how to detect that bugs and tell my users that "your connection is slow"!
I used speedtest.net for testing connection.

With this connection, i can connect but the webcam or voice doesn't work.

[image]

With this connection, i can connect and the webcam or voice works, so i guess it's a problem

[image]

So how i can tell the webrtc that I am staying slow connection, could webrtc handle with slow connection environment? I try to use Skype for testing slow connection, and Skype can connect without problem. I think that webrtc is requiring the fast connection as default for 2 peers.

My constraints code is very basic, only {audio: true}, nothing else. Please help me!!!

Comment: you can check the webrtc stats provided by the browser and see what the packet loss is. Are you forcing specific resolutions and framerates? Do you know for sure that they connected and that the Ice Connection status is Connected?

Comment: Also you can check bitrates (generally) from stats.  Firefox recently made min bandwidth dependent on resolution, so setting a lower capture resolution will work better on a poor connection.

Comment: Hi, is use {audio: true} for the constrain, so i am not forcing anything:(. The icecandidate doesn't tell, show any bugs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very likely the two connections have different NAT characteristics.  If both ends are behind symmetric NATs, you can't establish a direct connection between them; you need to have a TURN server configured to bounce packets off of. 8Mbps is *way* more than enough.  (Firefox in release maxes out at 2Mbps for video; in Nightly and IIRC 41/Aurora the bandwidth is proportional to the resolution, but VGA (the default in Firefox) maxes out at 1.3Mbps.

Try connecting using https://talky.io (which has a TURN server configured).

In Firefox, you can look at about:webrtc to see what network connections worked/didn't-work, etc.